# Is there any music studio programme on ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, music

I have a lots of music composition and i want to make my songs DVD.Is there any programme recommended to use? I hate Windows and Mac.But they are rich of theese programmes.Clearly I look for home studio programme that include piano sound and guitar  sound.and when i play piano on keyboard it must save my composition.Maybe it contain extra rythyms as Blues,Polka,and some chords..Thank you for your attentiton...

Comment: Can you give an example of a Windows program for what you want?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of "pro audio" applications in Ubuntu. You can look through the Software Center to find some. Some of the ones I use are `ardour`, `audacity`, `lmms`, `hydrogen`, and `zynaddsubfx`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in audio production or in software from that field. HOwever, I have messed around with a neat little program called lmms:

http://lmms.sourceforge.net/

from my understanding it can accept keyboard input:

http://lmms.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/0.4:Using_MIDI

And it does have a wide selection of sounds to mess around with. Most seemed to be geared towards the more techno type of stuff, but there are still quite a few "classical" sounds.

Again, I'm no expert, but I would definitely start here.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post exactly what you want to achieve. Especially regarding the DVD.

If it's a good DAW solution you're looking for then the best audio software for you will probably be [Ardour](http://ardour.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the alternative ditribution Ubuntu Studio, which comes with audio and sequencer applications.